# Not authenticated chrome instance when running an app using IIS Express in VS 2017 (client side debugging feature)

Tags: google-chrome, iis, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

It looks like the behavior when running an application with IIS Express changed.

In VS 2015, when i use IIS Express i get a new tab in my current instance of Google Chrome if i have one, otherwise i get a new instance with one tab, but the instance is authenticated:

[image: VS2015]

In VS 2017 RC, when i use IIS Express i get a new **not-authenticated** instance (no matter if i have another chrome instances):

[image: VS2017]

P.S: Disregard that there are two different applications, that is happening with all apps.

**Later Edit: This is happening in 7 March release too. Answer adjusted. It is a new default feature.**

Comment: You should use Help | Report an issue menu item to inform Microsoft. No need to post to Stack Overflow. It is a RC build which is just for that purpose.

Comment: It's funny that you consider telling me what my needs are. There are ~180 questions up there in visual-studio-2017 tag that are addressing this type of issues (moving from VS 2015 to 2017, deploying issues, IIS related issues and so on). I don't know exactly why you stopped here as you're not helping. And of course that i reported the problem. Thanks for downvote. There is no need for this type of attitude on SO.

Comment: well, so all of those questions are down voted like yours? An issue like yours is too broad as it involves a prerelease version of VS and a complex app like Chrome. You have to wait for a real expert that handles such things daily, which wouldn't be quicker than asking Microsoft directly.

Comment: I asked there too. This is just another way of trying to reach that expert. As vs2017 tag is available then it must be used. Using your logic, we mustn't discuss on SO a pre-release version of a software. So please go and try to remove the vs2017 tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encounter same problem when you're running VS 2017 RC as an Administrator. That won't change a thing in this scenario.

It looks like this issue was already addressed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2831/vs-2017-rc1-debugging-aspnet-project-with-chrome-d.html and it will be resolved by a future release.

As per Robert McKee (Debugging ASP.NET project with Chrome doesn't sign you in with your Google account):

> It's happening because it is getting launched with the following
>   command line: "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-first-run
>   --no-default-browser-check "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\rmckee\AppData\Local\Temp\chromeVSProfile\4020adf9-2540-4236-bad8-e8f3b6e23e4e"
>   "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chead%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3EPlease%20wait%20while%20we%20attach%3C/body%3E%3C!--4020adf9-2540-4236-bad8-e8f3b6e23e4e--%3E"
>   --remote-debugging-port=50384" so it is launching with a different profile.

**Realease edit:** This behavior is related to the possibility to to client-side debugging in VS 2017. To return to old behavior just uncheck javascript debugging for ASP.NET.

[image: JS Debug .NET]

More here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/